# I am struggling in data type of a single character in python. If it it is a string then comparison should be by string function

Tags: python

I am looking to add two numbers by accepting the response like this
12
+
56
Then I want to print 68 as output at the bottom of 56..it's showing some problems

```py
def sum(a, b):
    return (a + b)


def sub(a, b):
    return (a - b)


def mul(a, b):
    return (a*b)


def div(a, b):
    return (a / b)


x - int(input(""))
z = str(input(""))
y = int(input(""))
if (z == '+'):
    print(sum(x, y))
elif (z == '-'):
    print(sub(x, y))
elif (z == '*'):
    print(mul(x, y))
else:
    print(div(x, y))
```

Comment: Can you share your code and the error please?

Comment: Hey there please read Stackoverflow- https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask before asking a question

Comment: def sum(a,b):

return (a+b)

def sub(a,b): return (a-b)

def mul(a,b): return (a*b)

def div(a,b): return (a/b)

x-int(input("")) z=str(input(""))

y=int (input(""))

if(z=='+'):

print(s(x, y)) elif(z=='-'):

print (sub(x, y))

elif(z=='*'):

print(mul(x,y))

else:

print(div(x,y))

Comment: What is the error

Comment: I am new user here and I have posted a picture there but I didn't understand why they are not showing the picture.

Comment: I moved the code from the comment into your question body for you. Note: since the comment section collapsed whitespace I have no idea is this is accurate to your current indentation.

Comment: I see two problems. First is you are calling the sum function incorrectly. Use ```sum(x,y)``` instead of ```s(x,y)```.  Second is you are assigning the first input using ```-``` when it should be ```=```

Comment: Instead of a picture can u copy the error and paste within a code block. Click edit on your question and add it. You should see a code block option in the question editor. Use that

Comment: Why int(input ("")) is issue sir

Comment: `x - int(input(""))` is the only remaining problem. Did you mean `x = int(input(""))`?

Comment: Yes it's sum(x,y)

Comment: Error is --(base) C:\Users\HP\PyProgram>conda activate Anaconda3

Could not find conda environment: Anaconda3 You can list all discoverable environments with conda info --envs`.

(base) C:\Users\HP\PyProgram>C:/ProgramData/Anaconda3/python.exe C:/Users/HP/PyProgram/function_in_deep.py

Comment: Please provide the expected see [MRE - Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).
Show where the intermediate results deviate from the ones you expect.  We should be able to paste a single block of your code into file, run it, and reproduce your problem.  This also lets us test any suggestions in your context.

Comment: If  you have clarifications critical to your question, you must edit it into the question, not leave it in the comments below.  Please go through the [intro tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help) and [how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)  to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers.

Comment: Your posted program hangs waiting for input.  Do not expect us to provide test data: simply replace your `input` with a test case that elicits the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Um I have read the comment and try to summarise it here :) ?

- `x = int(input(""))`  use `=` instead of `-` to declare a variable and I think this is a typo ?
- `s is not defined`  to sum to number we can directly use the `sum` function , in my opinion , no need to create a function for it : e.g.

```
x = input('')
y = input('')
print(sum([int(x), int(y)]))
```

full code ( changed ) :

```
def sum(a, b):
    return (a + b)


def sub(a, b):
    return (a - b)


def mul(a, b):
    return (a*b)


def div(a, b):
    return (a / b)


x = int(input("number : "))  # x - int(input(""))  -->  x = int(input(""))  # typo i think
z = str(input("operator : "))
y = int(input("number : "))

'''
I change the x y z here : how to handle empty input
one of the way is using the if else statement
if x y z is empty --> nothing is done :

num1 = input("number : ")  # and I prefer meaningful variable names : )
operator = input("operator : ")
num2 = input("number : ")

if num1.strip() == '' or num2.strip() == '':
    print('error message')
'''
'''
or you can also make a function to recur it :

def askInput():
    num1 = input("number : ")
    operator = input("operator : ")
    num2 = input("number : ")

    if num1.strip() == '' or num2.strip() == '':
        print("error")
        askInput()

    return num1, operator, num2

x, y, z = askInput()
print(x, y, z)  # just to test if it works , you can delete it in you code : )
... # add sub mul div function here
'''

if (z == '+'):
    print(sum(x, y))  # s is not defined --> i think it should be the function  sum()  right ?

    # but  sum  is already a python built-in stuff ( idk what it call sry )  so not need to
    # write a function for it i think
    
elif (z == '-'):
    print(sub(x, y))
    
elif (z == '*'):  # <-- i think it would be clear that  z == '*'  ?
    print(mul(x, y))
    
else:
    print(div(x, y))
```

Comment: Thank you to everyone. But sir I have seen by experiment you can't make blank in the input ("") you have to write something

Comment: sorry i dont get what you mean 
do you mean I cant input nothing in the input statement ?

Comment: Yes Sir I have tried everything like - input() ,input(' ') , input(" ") , input('   '), input ("   ").. everytime I recieved an error but when I wrote something in the input section it's working

Comment: ohh ys 
maybe you can try handle this kind of error by type checking ( one of the way ) 
I'll add this to the answer : )

Comment: def sum(a,b):
    return (a+b)
def sub(a,b):
    return (a-b)
def mul(a,b):
    return (a*b)
def div(a,b):
    return (a/b)
x=int(input("First Number : "))
z=str(input("Process : "))
y=int(input("Second Number : "))
if(z=='+'):
   print(sum(x,y))
elif(z=='-'):
    print(sub(x,y))
elif(z=='*'):
   print(mul(x,y))
else:
    print(div(x,y))